# How to print on windows shared printer with python?

Tags: linux, python

How can i print on a SMB shared printer on a windows client with python on a different computer with gnu/linux?

Comment: python has `cups` module.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12854206/python-share-name-printer

Comment: Thanks but i prefer a pure python solution if is possible.

Comment: use `pysmb`,`pysmbc`,`thermalprinter` , `win32print`, `pprint`